# Access params[] and local attributes in static class as *_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to refactor some code and move some of my before_filter's from the controller to a class.

### Before:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :find_user

   def find_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
   end
end

...
```

### After

```
class FindUserFilter
    def self.filter(controller)
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_filter FindUserFilter
end

class GuestbookController < ApplicationController
   before_filter FindUserFilter
end
```

This results in an error because neither `params[:id]` nor `@user` is available/definable in the `FindUserFilter`-class.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code must be run within the @controller scope.
One solution would be

```
class FindUserFilter
  def self.filter(controller)
    controller.instance_eval do
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```